# Can't stop Skype from intercepting phone calls

Tags: calls, default-applications, skype

I am using  the HTC One 806w with Android 4.4.3 version. When I attempt to call from phone, it showed me a screen whereby I could select the Skype application. I selected it but I'd like to remove the default application. I have dialled the number, but I keep accessing calls from my phone.

I tried going to settings >> apps >> skype >> defaults...
but found that I had no defaults set. I tried clearing the preferences and the cache also. I am unable to find a viable solution..

If anyone knows anything about this, please help assist me in finding the solution.

Comment: possible duplicate: http://android.stackexchange.com/q/97875/1465

Answer (score 0):

Try to reinstall Skype and the you can call a number with the default dialer.